# Lombok - retain field's annotation in constructor input params

Tags: java, guice, lombok

Lombok misses field's annotation while auto generating constructor. Is there a way to retain field's annotation in constructor input params?

Class to generate constructor,

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Inject))
public class Test {

    @Named("MyField")
    private final String field;
    @Named("MyHandler")
    private final SomeHandler handler;
}
```

Generated class :

```
public class Test {

    @Named("MyField")
    private final String field;
    @Named("MyField")
    private final SomeHandler handler;

    @Inject
    public Test(final String field, final SomeHandler handler) {
        this.field = field;
        this.handler = handler;
    }
}
```

Desired class :

```
public class Test {

    @Named("MyField")
    private final String field;
    @Named("MyHandler")
    private final SomeHandler handler;

    @Inject
    public Test(@Named("MyField")final String field, 
                @Named("MyHandler")final SomeHandler handler) {
        this.field = field;
        this.handler = handler;
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think this ever got implemented as per: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/project-lombok/2vaujDkV8Nw

Comment: @Cheetah I'm afraid, you're right. I started implementing it years ago, but it was more complicated than I thought. Nobody cared and I found out that I myself needed it only rarely and there was a workaround.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

In version [v1.18.4](https://projectlombok.org/changelog) Lombok added support for copying specific annotations. Meaning, that if you put following setting to `lombok.config`:

```
lombok.copyableAnnotations += com.google.inject.name.Named
```

and apply following Lombok annotations to your class:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Inject))
public class Hello {
    @NonNull @Named("my-name") String name;
}
```

the `@Named` annotation should be copied to your generated constructor argument.

Limitations: this does not work when [annotation can't be put on a field](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/1335#issuecomment-893946033) or [annotation on a field overrides constructor initialization](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/1528#issuecomment-608537264)

Answer (score 12):

There's no such feature and it looks like nobody cares. I [proposed it once](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/project-lombok/2vaujDkV8Nw) and started to implement it, but gave up (no demand and too much work).

It could look like

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor=@__(@Inject))
public class Something {
    @OnConstructor(@Named("userName"))
    private final String userName;

    @OnConstructor(@Named("userPassword"))
    private final String userPassword;

    private final int anotherField;

    private final int yetAnotherField;
}
```

or maybe just

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor(
     onConstructor=@__(@Inject),
     moveToConstructorArg=@__(@Named))
public class Something {
    @Named("userName")
    private final String userName;

    @Named("userPassword")
    private final String userPassword;

    private final int anotherField;

    private final int yetAnotherField;
}
```

or it could be controlled using `lombok.config` as you probably want all `@Named` annotations to be moved to the constructor.

I'm afraid, if you want it, then you have to do it yourself (my incomplete implementation might help you a bit).

FTR: There's a [feature request](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1335) now.