# lombok and guice injection

Tags: dependency-injection, guice, lombok

I'm new to lombok and guice injection, I could get the general concept but I ran into some code which I don't understand and can't search due to the syntax. Following is the code, can someone help me understand this?

```
import com.google.inject.Inject;
import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;

@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE, onConstructor = @__({ @Inject }))
public class SomeClass {
...
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

This is going to add a constructor with all fields as parameters, with `@Inject` annotation and `private` modifier, so your code will be expanded to:

```
import com.google.inject.Inject;

public class SomeClass {
    
    @Inject
    private SomeClass() {
    }
}
```

This is assuming there are no fields in the class. If you have some fields, then they will be added to the constructor, for example:

```
import com.google.inject.Inject;
import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;

@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE, onConstructor = @__({ @Inject }))
public class SomeClass {
    private String name;
}
```

Will become:

```
import com.google.inject.Inject;

public class SomeClass {
    private String name        

    @Inject
    private SomeClass(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Please note, that this won't work in Guice anyway, as it requires a constructor that is not private, per [this documentation](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/InjectionPoints).

Comment: "Please note, that this won't work in Guice anyway, as it requires a constructor that is not private"  This is only true if the constructor doesn't have the `@Inject` annotation.  With the annotation, Guice will handle it fine, except AOP won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure Lombok retains any `@Named` annotations you have added!

Otherwise the code below for example will fail to inject:

```
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE, onConstructor = @__({@Inject}))
public class SomeClass {
    @Named("example")
    private String exampleString;
}

public class ExampleModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(String.class)
          .annotatedWith(Names.named("example"))
          .toInstance("Hello, world!");
    }
}
```

See this answer: [Lombok retain fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42526279/lombok-retain-fields-annotation-in-constructor-input-params). You want to add

```
lombok.copyableAnnotations += com.google.inject.name.Named
```

to your `lombok.config` file.